# Using Python script tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, python-script-tool

i have created the following tool to add two fields in a table and do a calculation in order to put the tool to ModelBuilder.

For some reason when i am going to put it as an input in an another tool it doesn't appear.

I think i have done something wrong with
 1. SetParameter and also
 2. i haven't managed to save it as a feature class and it's only in memory.In addition i don't have a gdb or an mxd.

Also i set set parameter as an output feature class at tool's parameters but it didn't make any difference.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2, any suggestion?

```
 # Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.overwriteoutput = True

# Set environment settings
inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inFeature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outFc = arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, "")
env.workspace = inWorkspace

# Set local variables
fieldName1 = "bear_60"
fieldName13 = "distance"

# Execute AddField for 2 new fields
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, fieldName1, "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NON_NULLABLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, fieldName13, "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NON_NULLABLE")

# Calculate Field bear_60
inTable = inFeature
fieldname = fieldName1
expression = "getCalc(!aspect!)"
codeblock = """def getCalc(aspect):
    if aspect > 300:
        bear_60 = (aspect + 60) - 360
    else:
        bear_60 = aspect + 60
    return bear_60"""
# Execute CalculateField 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldname, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)

# Calculate Field distance
inTable = inFeature
fieldname = fieldName13
expression = "getCalc(!distance!)"
codeblock = """def getCalc(distance):
    return 10000"""
# Execute CalculateField 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldname, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually produce an output from your tool, only modify the input file. Although you have an argument for outFc you're not creating the output. Notice: all fields added and field calculations are performed on the input feature class.

If you change your outFc to:

```
outFc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

the user can specify an output path. Then you can make a copy of the input feature class using:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeature,outFc).
```

Then just use outFc for the adding/calculating fields:

```
inTable = outFc
```

This will leave the original file as-is but give you an output that you will be able to pass to your next step in the model builder.

For further reference see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000